# can "is" operator be factorized in c#?

Tags: c#

I want to use `is` operator in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) condition statement. my code is like this:

```
 public static string returnProperColumnValue(string columnName, object columnValue)
 {
    if (columnValue is int || columnValue is float || columnValue is long || ..... ))
    {
        return columnValue.ToString();
    }
    else if (columnValue is string)
    {
        return "'" + columnValue + "'";
    }
    else if (columnValue.GetType().IsGenericType && columnValue is IDictionary)
    {
        var dictionaryType = columnValue.GetType().GetGenericArguments().First().Name;

        //to do
        return "";
    }
    else if (columnValue.GetType().IsGenericType && (columnValue is IEnumerable))
    {
        var listType = columnValue.GetType().GetGenericArguments().Single().Name;

        if (listType is int || ....... )
            return columnName + "+" + "[" + columnValue.ToString() + "]";
        else if (listType is string)
            return columnName + "+" + "{'" + columnValue.ToString() + "'} ";
    }
    return "";
}
```

I want to check lots of `variable types` in the `if` clause.
Therefore, I want to use `is` operator in shorter way like this:

```
public void properColumnValue(object columnValue)
{
    if (columnValue is ( int || decimal || ... ) )
    {
        //do stuff for int
    } 

    //other conditions
}
```

Is it possible to factorize the `is` operation?

Comment: create your own method accepting `params Type`

Comment: This sounds like a terrible idea. What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: No, it is not possible. You should just write the code like you have already done. If you showed more of what you intended to do with that knowledge, different ways of doing that may give other answers, but isolated checking if an object is type A or type B, etc. with no common interface or base type, the multiple `is` expressions are as good as it gets.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen  I updated the code!

Comment: I would turn that code upside down. Start with a null-check, then do all the specifics, if none of the specific types match (and int, decimal etc. are not what I'm talking about here), simply return `columnValue.ToString()` at the very end.

Comment: When you post code here, review how the code looks and make sure indenting is consistant and also consider remove extra consecutive blank lines to reduce the amout of scrolling needed to see all of the code.

Answer (score 4):

No, the `is` operator cannot be factored like this. Maybe you could use the `IsInstanceOfType` method, which is a member of `System.Type`:

```
public void properColumnValue(object columnValue)
{
    Type[] types = new[] {typeof (int), typeof (decimal), typeof (long)};

    bool b = types.Any(x => x.IsInstanceOfType(columnValue));
    if (b)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks.I updated that! there are more types like dictionary and enumerable types in there!  In my case, it is more convenient for me to use "is" operation

Comment: @DooshizePlusPlus sometimes _convenient_ and _possible_ do not align very well.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from Kapol's idea you can also use the `Contains` method to see if the actual type of the value contained in your `columnValue` is a member of the array:

```
public void properColumnValue(object columnValue)
{
    Type[] number_types = new[] {typeof (int), typeof (decimal), typeof (long)};
    if (number_types.Contains(columnValue?.GetType()))
    {
        // convert to long, or whatever you need it to be:
        long value = Convert.ToInt64(columnValue);
        //... do something with the value
    }
}
```

Or you can make that a `static readonly` array at the class level to speed things up a tiny bit:

```
static readonly Type[] number_types = new[] {typeof (int), typeof (decimal), typeof (long)};
public void properColumnValue(object columnValue)
{
    if (number_types.Contains(columnValue?.GetType()))
    {
        // convert to long, or whatever you need it to be:
        long value = Convert.ToInt64(columnValue);
        //... do something with the value
    }
}
```

At least that way you're only creating the array once.

Comment: DavidG had already posted and then deleted this, because it doesn't do what the OP asked. Copying my comment from there: "This doesn't check whether `columnValue is <type>`, this checks whether `columnValue.GetType() == typeof(<type>)`, which is different from what the OP asked. Firstly, it blows up if `columnValue == null`. Secondly, it doesn't handle inheritance." And the OP's response: "thanks @DavidG . I specifically want to check for "is" operator." indicates that this really isn't what the OP is after.

Comment: @hvd OK... but I don't think I can be held accountable for not reading something that isn't there anymore :)  Also since you can't derive from any of the mentioned types (since they are either value types or sealed) the inheritence question does not arise.

Comment: I wasn't blaming you :) I like the `?.` approach you use in here. The OP may well have non-sealed types in the `...` omitted in the question though.

Answer (score 0):

Every logical operation requires both left and right side arguments, and `is` operator is not a method you cannot use it like `columnValue is ( int || decimal || ...)`

What you can do is create custom extension method for this, and pass types (or string names of types) as parameters :

```
public static class Helper
{
    static Dictionary<string, Type> _types = new Dictionary<string, Type>()
    {
        {"int", typeof(int)}, {"string", typeof(string)}, 
        {"double", typeof(double)}, {"decimal", typeof(decimal)},             
        // ... etc
    };

    public static bool Is<T>(this T instance, params string[] types)
    {
        Type iType = instance.GetType();
        for (int i = 0; i < types.Length; i++)
            if (_types.ContainsKey(types[i]) && _types[types[i]] == iType)
                return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

And use it :

```
public void properColumnValue(object columnValue)
{
    if (columnValue.Is("int", "decimal", "double") ... ))
    {
        //do stuff for int, decimal or double
    } 
}
```

Comment: thanks.I updated that! there are more types like dictionary and enumerable types in there!  In my case, it is more convenient for me to use "is" operation

Comment: @DooshizePlusPlus you can use `is` operator but only like : `if(a is B && a is C && a is D ..and so on)`. It's the only way to use it with current scenario